# I am getting error about the sql transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am try to insert the two connected command table by transaction

But I am getting this error.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near
>   the keyword 'SELECT'. Incorrect syntax near ')'. konum:

---

```
        SqlConnection baglanti = s.baglan();
        SqlCommand vtislem1 = new SqlCommand("Insert urun (urunad,urunadet) values(@urunad,@urunadet)", baglanti);
        SqlCommand vtislem2 = new SqlCommand("Insert urunfiyat (UrunID,UrunFiyat) values(SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('urun'),@UrunFiyat)", baglanti);


        vtislem1.Parameters.Add("@urunad", Label1.Text);
        vtislem1.Parameters.Add("@urunadet", Label1.Text);

        vtislem2.Parameters.Add("@UrunFiyat", Label1.Text);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a sql syntax error.
use this;

```
Insert urunfiyat (UrunID,UrunFiyat) values((SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('urun')),@UrunFiyat)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
   SqlCommand vtislem2 = new SqlCommand("Insert urunfiyat (UrunID,UrunFiyat) SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('urun'),@UrunFiyat", baglanti);
```

`VALUES` is only necessary when providing a list of variables.